# Using two features of other model as input to shallow CNN gives error

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to use two features from other model. feature one is 3 class and feature two is 4 class. i concatenate it and then use it as input for other model, but i am facing an error.

my code:

```
 p1 = modelFirst.predict(test_xR)
 p2 = modelSecond.predict(test_xI)
 input_shape = (None,1, 7)
 inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input (shape=input_shape)
 combined = np.concatenate([p1, p2], 1)
 z = combined
 z = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(z)
 z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation = 'relu', name = "fc0")(z)
 outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,activation='softmax',name = 'fc1')(z)
 modelFinal = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, *outputs)
 modelFinal.build(1)
 modelFinal.summary()
modelFinal.compile(optimizer = "adam",loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=["accuracy"])'''
```

Error:

```
c:\users\documents\python-games\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in build(self, input_shape)
    379     valid_types = (tuple, list, tf.TensorShape, dict)
    380     if not isinstance(input_shape, valid_types):
--> 381       raise ValueError('Specified input shape is not one of the valid types. '
    382                        'Please specify a batch input shape of type tuple or '
    383                        'list of input shapes. User provided '

ValueError: Specified input shape is not one of the valid types. Please specify a batch input shape of type tuple or list of input shapes. User provided input type: <class 'int'>.
```

Comment: The error message is very clear, you passed an integer as input shape instead of a list/tuple.

Comment: Hi Dr. Snoopy I am trying to pass probability of two other networks as a feature input which is (255, 7). Kindly help me to fix this issue please

Comment: Are you actually trying to understand the problem? Here is the line that passed the input shape: modelFinal.build(1)

Comment: Yes, you are right I am passing (1) but I have tried input different like (227,227,3)then it say I passed more than two parameters. When I passed one parameter to see then I get this error. My apologies Dr. Snoopy for confusion. I appreciate your response.

Comment: You need to pass a tuple or list, not multiple parameters, do you know the difference?

Comment: Hi Dr. Snoopy, I will appreciate if you guide me with example as per my code that will be helpful. I know tople and list but I am confused how and what to pass here

Comment: modelFinal.build((227,227,3))